# how to prevent a variable from resetting when reopening the app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save variables after application shut down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671556/how-to-save-variables-after-application-shut-down)

I am making an Iphone app in a single view application, using objective-c and I want to be able keep variables recording scores  to control unlockable characters, highscores, etc.

The problem is everytime I close and reopen the app, the variables reset.

Does anyone know how to make a variable that will never reset on re-opening?

Answer (score 4):

On iOS you store variables between runs by using `NSUserDefaults`. 
See an example code below:

```
#define HSMEMORY @"hsMemory"  // used to prevent errors in writing it repeatedly

    // Store initial default values. Do this at the beginning of the App like in AppDelegate before the values are used and accessed.
    // This will set the initial value when the App is first run and nothing has been stored in previous runs.
        NSNumber *defaultMemory = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0];
        NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary
                                         dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         defaultMemory, HSMEMORY, nil];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
```

To access the variable use:

```
NSNumber *memory = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:HSMEMORY];
```

To reset the variable use:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:memory forKey:HSMEMORY];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you say a 'variable' you mean a NSString,so in this case you can use NSUserDefaults to achieve this.But remember that NSUserDefaults,as the name says is supposed to store small amounts of data,so don't keep using it too much.

**To save a NSString:**

```
//Initialize NSUserDefaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//Store the desired value
[defaults setObject:@"TEXT TO SAVE OR NSSTRING" forKey:@"CHOOSE A KEY-NAME"];
//To retrieve the text when the app launch
NSString *value_retrieved = [defaults objectForKey@"YOUR KEY-NAME"];
```

**To save a BOOL key**

```
//Initialize NSUserDefaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//Save the Boolean
[defaults setBool:YES OR NO forKey:@"CHOOSE A KEY-NAME"];
//Retrieve the Boolean
[defaults boolForKey:@"YOUR KEY-NAME"];
```